# How to get Basemap to work with xarray plotting for time slices

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, python-xarray

I need to draw a xarray.DataArray object onto a shapefile with Basemap.

The source data contains a few days' data.

I would like each dataset to be drawn on the shapefile with Basemap.

```
... ...
shapefile1="./shp/CFA_DISTRICT_BODY"

# Select 3 days' datasets
da_criteria_1or0_hourly_rolled_resampled_sel_slice = da_criteria_1or0_hourly_rolled_resampled.sel(time=slice('2017-01-01', '2017-01-03'))

# Draw each day's dataset and set them drawn horizontally
p = da_criteria_1or0_hourly_rolled_resampled_sel_slice.plot(levels=[0,1,2], x='longitude', y='latitude', col='time', col_wrap=3)

# Draw the shapefile
map = Basemap(llcrnrlat=-39.2,urcrnrlat=-33.9,llcrnrlon=140.8,urcrnrlon=150.0,resolution='i')
map.readshapefile(shapefile1, 'CFA_DISTRICT_BODY', linewidth=0.5)

plt.show()
```

The issue with the code above is only the Day 3's dataset is drawn on the shapefile.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only define a single `Basemap`. That'll apply to the last active axes.

Instead you would create a Basemap for each axes in the FacetGrid.
The idea would be along the lines of

```
grid = data.plot(...)

for ax in grid.axes.flatten():
    map = Basemap(..., ax=ax)
    map.readshapefile(...)

plt.show()
```